# Div strap: after resizing window to certain point background image starting to shrink

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make strap filled with oversized image. The idea is, that image have some fixed size and do not change. The div that image is in, while making browser window bigger, should reveal hidden part of the picture. And I achive it. But there is a problem... in some point, when the browser window getting smaller image is scaled down. 
I expect that at that height of this image will be equal to height of container, and the sides will be cropped, while image will keep its proportions.

Some code:

```css
.picbanner {
  background: url(https://IMG) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

JSF:

https://jsfiddle.net/kshdrynp/2/

Thank You in advance,
GT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `background-size` to `cover`:

```css
.picbanner {
  background: url(https://IMG) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1fuqyvLk/